Script for "Leave touchpad on when a mouse is connected."
Is it possible to toggle the checkbox "Leave touchpad on when a mouse is connected." in Windows 11 settings via a script? It would help me to run it with a shortcut rather than removing the mouse dongle.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
